# DDL trigger not working when trying to drop table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a simple DDL trigger that won't let me drop any table inside my database

The trigger creates but I get an error when I try to test the trigger if it is working or not:

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Exercitiul12
BEFORE DROP ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Nu puteti sterge tabelul ' || ora_dict_obj_name);
END;
/

BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Restaurant;
END;
/`
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: It would help to show the error; but you can't do a static `drop` (or any DDL) from PL/SQL. Why do you have the begin/end around that drop statement? (Also - did you mean to create a trigger that stops you dropping anything, or just tables?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
create or replace trigger delete_disabling_trigger
  before drop on database
begin
    if(ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME = 'MY_TABLE') then --and ORA_DICT_OBJ_OWNER = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'  
    dbms_output.put_line('delete_disabling_trigger');
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Cant delete this table');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: This forum is made up of volunteers who try to help others by donating their time and expertise. Having said that, it would be nice to know if their solutions helped solve your issue. If I didn't please explain why and add more details. If it did, please upvote and accept the answer.